# Is it possible to use custom domains without owner verification with appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an application hosted by Google Appengine and I need to serve it using custom domain. Is it possible to use custom domains without owner verification?

Answer (score 2):

In order for a custom domain to serve your GAE app, Google must verify that you are indeed an owner of the domain (DNS entries often need to be added, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you DNS provider can do a 301/302 HTTP redirect, you can set it up to redirect to your app's underlying app_id.appspot.com URL, but the user would be seeing it after the first page load in the browser address bar.

Without validation though, you won't be able to host a site directly.